# Image in mail using python?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I write a script to send mail including image in html format but unfortunately when mail sent i found image like below

please advise?

[image when received in destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1JdZ.jpg)

script:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import os


#Credentials data
host="smtp.gmail.com"
port=587
from_email="engminazarief@gmail.com"
to_email="mina.zarif@outlook.com"
password="yallakora@2018"
subject="Hello World"

try:
#Mail connection
email_conn=smtplib.SMTP(host,port)
email_conn.ehlo()
email_conn.starttls()
email_conn.login(from_email,password)

#Mail data
msg=MIMEMultipart("alternative")
msg['Subject']=subject
msg['From']=from_email
msg['To']=to_email
## HTML
html_body= """\
<body>
<p style="text-indent: 4em;">
<img src="~path~\page5.jpg">
</p>

</body>
"""
body=MIMEText(html_body,"html")
msg.attach(body)

#Send mail
email_conn.sendmail(from_email,to_email,msg.as_string())
email_conn.quit()
except smtplib.SMTPException:
"error sending mail"
```

Comment: It is a image that should be attached (I think you are not attaching the image) or it is internet? (in the second case, the path is not ok).

Comment: See the [examples from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

Comment: Thanks bro for your comment I adjust path and get same result